# Codeigniter - removing index.php causes links to break

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am experiencing this issue with index.php in the URL whereby when its removed the links to my controller are no longer working ?

I have modified the following:

**config.php:**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

URI protocol is as was:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ampp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have also verified with `phpinfo();` that module `mod_rewrite` is loaded.

Current url is in this format:
http://localhost:100/ampp/

The login form on the main page:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('Auth/login') ?>">
    <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>

    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

However when i submit the form I am getting 404

```
Not Found

The requested URL /ampp/Auth/login was not found on this server.
```

I have checked log files to see what the problem is but the log files just indicate that Auth is not found.

```
File does not exist: /var/www/html/ampp/Auth, referer: http://localhost:100/ampp/
```

Technically the file is not located in the directory the log files are claiming (which is true as the file is in /ampp/application/controller/) but i have thought that Codeigniter would resolve this appropriately.

**Tree structure**

```
   .
├── cache
│   └── index.html
├── config
│   ├── autoload.php
│   ├── config.php
│   ├── constants.php
│   ├── database.php
│   ├── doctypes.php
│   ├── foreign_chars.php
│   ├── hooks.php
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── memcached.php
│   ├── migration.php
│   ├── mimes.php
│   ├── profiler.php
│   ├── routes.php
│   ├── smileys.php
│   └── user_agents.php
├── controllers
│   ├── Auth.php
│   ├── Home.php
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── Login.php
│   └── Main.php
├── core
│   └── index.html
├── helpers
│   └── index.html
├── hooks
│   └── index.html
├── index.html
├── language
│   ├── english
│   │   └── index.html
│   └── index.html
├── libraries
│   └── index.html
├── logs
│   └── index.html
├── models
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── UserAuth.php
│   └── User.php
├── third_party
│   └── index.html
└── views
    ├── errors
    │   ├── cli
    │   │   ├── error_404.php
    │   │   ├── error_db.php
    │   │   ├── error_exception.php
    │   │   ├── error_general.php
    │   │   ├── error_php.php
    │   │   └── index.html
    │   ├── html
    │   │   ├── error_404.php
    │   │   ├── error_db.php
    │   │   ├── error_exception.php
    │   │   ├── error_general.php
    │   │   ├── error_php.php
    │   │   └── index.html
    │   └── index.html
    ├── home.php
    ├── index.html
    ├── login.php
    └── report.php
```

**Auth.php Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('UserAuth');

                $this->output->set_header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');
                $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
                $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
                $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
        }
        public function index() {
                $session = $this->session->userdata('authUser');
                if(!$session) {
                        redirect('login','refresh');
                } else {
                        $this->propagate($session['id']);
                }
        }
        public function login() {
                $this->verifylogin();
        }
        public function verifylogin() {
                $email = $this->input->post('email');
                $password = $this->input->post('password');

                $data = array('email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password);
                $validation = $this->UserAuth->validateUser($data);

                if($validation == false) {
                        //show login with erro message - no error message implemented
                        $this->load->view('login');
                } else {
                        $result = $validation;
                        $sess_array = array();
                        foreach($result as $row) {
                                $sess_array = array(
                                        'authID' => sha1($result[0]->id),
                                        'id' => $result[0]->id,
                                        'email' => $result[0]->email
                                        );
                                $this->session->set_userdata('authUser', $sess_array);
                        }
                        redirect('home','refresh');
                }
        }
        public function logout() {
                $this->session->unset_userdata('authUser');
                $this->session->sess_destroy();
                redirect('Main', 'refresh');
        }
}
```

**.htaccess check**

I thought i give it a go and it seems like it could be the problem with the actual `.htaccess` file. Why?

Well i have replaced the content of the `.htaccess` file with this:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Yet i am still able to view main login page (despite the fact that .htaccess should not allow me)

**UPDATE:**
Ok since i have noticed that any .htaccess file is not working i went about digging to find out why its not working.

And as a result the issue was with the vhost configuration...

```
<Directory "/"> //<-------- This was the issue.
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>


<Directory "/var/www/html/ampp"> //<------- This has resolved then issue.
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Try removing the `RewriteBase` and changing this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ampp/index.php/$1 [L]`, this is the setup I have.

Comment: @Blinkydamo Nope - still same issue

Comment: Keep in mind you should also set the base_url in codeigniter

Comment: @killstreet base_url is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, the issue was not with the `.htaccess` it self nor Codeigniter but Apache configuration.

```
<Directory "/"> //<-------- This was the issue.
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>


<Directory "/var/www/html/ampp"> //<------- This has resolved then issue.
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your Auth is a controller class and login is a method of that class. Simply check filename of your class file i.e. check filename of your Auth Controller, it should be first character uppercase, "Auth.php". And then change action of your form to

```
site_url('auth/login')
```

Note: auth with lowercase in url.

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Also try adding slash "/" infront of index.php in your htaccess

Comment: i.e. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: i don't think Lower Case will be the problem

Comment: it could be.... because recent version of codeigniter is case sensitive unix/linux system.

Comment: @puncoz Nope neither helped - same issue

Comment: ok once try changing your default controller in routes.php to 'auth/login' and load root in browser

Comment: @puncoz so i have done that, i have also predefined login credentials to see if the redirect works and it does work but then after redirect i get the same error that Home controller is not found

Comment: @MaciejCygan if after setting auth/login as your default controller loads your login page then the problem is with mod redirection otherwise problem could be with your server/apache. try adding index.php in your url once, if it works then we need to look for the problem with apache mod rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.htaccess` to this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

**In config**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:100/ampp/';
```

---

**In Form**

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url();?>auth/login">
```

---

> > **Before that make sure there is controller call `auth` and method call `login`**

Comment: what you change and where ??

Comment: I have applied your suggested .htaccess but the issue still persists.

Comment: As far as I am aware the controller name should be capital isn't it ? Also the base url is already set to that value

Comment: file name should be `Auth.php` and class name should be same too

Comment: So the filename and class name is capital already, base url is already set - i have amended the form action to your suggestion but to no avail - same issue

Comment: show me structure of your controller. add in your question

Comment: @MaciejCygan No i mean path image of outside file system of your controller

Comment: I have added tree structure

Comment: all looks ok it should work fine. i hope u have placed `.htaccess` outside application folder.

Comment: Yes its in the root folder not application. Have a look at my .htaccess check

Comment: remove all your htaccess and add mine.

Comment: I have already done that earlier and as said it was not working - So i did this check just now to see if the .htaccess is actually working but it appears its not